# Regular Expression, greedy over |

Tags: php, regex, regex-greedy

for some weeks im working with regular expressions in php.
Now my question: Is there any way, to make the RegEx greedy over `|` ?

for example subject: `012345abcdefghijklm`

pattern: `/(abcde|abcdefghi)/`   will extract `abcde`, although `abcdefghi` is the greedier match.

The only way i found, is to sort the RegEx by the highest length of possibly matches

Thanks

Comment: did you want to capture `abcde` and `abcdefghi` into two separate groups?

Comment: The example from above is very simple. In fact its a bit harder. Its not like the second is exactly the same, like the first expression at the beginning. The first is a complete different expression, that accidentally matches the second too.

Comment: What's your actual question is?

Comment: I just wanted to know, if there is something like a mode that captures the whole RegEx instead of finishing after the first match. (no, global is not what i meant)

Comment: you could try this http://regex101.com/r/uI2oL4/1 to capture both strings in a seperate groups.

Comment: Define "greedy over |". For this specific case it's better to rearrange. If you meant skipping matches when one alternation is matched use atomic groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way other than reordering the elements or by adding an optional non-capture group.

Regular Expression engines are eager. Because of the way the **Alternation meta-character works (|)**, [the first possible match exits the alternation clause](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Either re-order the possible choices (`/(abcdefghi|abcde)/`) or use an optional non-capture group (`/(abcde(?:fghi)?)/`).

Answer (score 0):

Here you should use:

```
abcde(?:fghi)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution. But it provides alternative other than the sorting one:

```
(abcde(?!fghi)|abcdefghi)
```

Comment: This is slightly worse in performance over `/(abcdefghi|abcde)/`